# Why Date() has different type from new Date() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

When I run in the console

```
typeof new Date()
```

I get `object`. But if I evaluate

```
typeof Date()
```

I get `string`. Why?

Comment: Did you look at any documentation ? Like the MDN for example ?

Comment: I checked this one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Well... what's not clear in this page ?

Comment: Yes, the upvoted and correct answer just copy/pasted the text from the page you linked.

Comment: In case you're confused that both `new Date()` and `Date()` look extremely similar when entered on a console: `new Date()` gives you a full *`Date` object* with properties and methods and so on, which just happens to look like a date string when printed as value to a console. It's not just a different type, it's an entirely different thing you're getting back.

Comment: I couldn't get the real question here?

Answer (score 2):

From [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> Note: JavaScript Date objects can only be instantiated by calling
>   JavaScript Date as a constructor: calling it as a regular function
>   (i.e. without the new operator) will return a string rather than a
>   Date object; unlike other JavaScript object types, JavaScript Date
>   objects have no literal syntax.

Comment: @Alex Because that's what the documentation says it does and that's the way it's implemented.

Comment: I see. But what maybe the cause for that?

Comment: @Taken That sounds more like an additional clarification than a reason for that behaviour.

Comment: It's so that you can get the date from calling it as a function, rather than having to instantiate a date object every time.  You only do that if you require the public methods.  It's a bit uncommon, but really not a big deal.